# SQL select using condition that a column starts with a certain string

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I am using sql.
How to select all items from a table.
where a column (varchar) path is start with a certain string : "stringABC"

```
select * from ATable where path like 'stringABC';
```

The above sql is wrong, can any one help me to fix it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * 
from ATable 
where path like 'stringABC%'
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from ATAble where path like 'string%'